# Unearned Tag badge

Tags: discussion, bug, tag-badges

I've earned the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) bronze badge few months ago which is shown as earned in [Help Center > All](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=all):

[image]

But if I switch to [Help Center > Unearned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=unearned) I still see it as a badge that I don't earn (yet).

Is it still displayed because I don't have a bronze tag badge in, well, *all* tags? Is this a <strike>bug</strike> feature?

Comment: It does seem kind of silly to list tag badges under Unearned considering you could probably never achieve badges in every single tag where it is possible.

Comment: Hold on a minute, I'll double-check with Jon.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi He have *only* [702](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges&sort=class) of them.

Comment: Weird, just noticed it's the same for me and the bronze python badge

Comment: If you mean 'it' in *I still see it as* to be the [Bronze Badge] I see the same and I have the Delphi bronze badge.

Comment: It's probably exactly what you guessed. I only say this because (on meta, the only place I have a tag badge) if I look at the _earned_ tab on the badges page, I see bronze badge under tag badges. If I look at _unearned_ I see the same as you. I currently have two bronze badges here on Meta, so I assume (this is just a guess of course) that it is indeed just because you still have bronze tag badges you can earn.

Comment: @Kendra I will *always* have bronze tag badge that I can earn

Comment: Exactly, so you'll always have _unearned_ bronze tag badges, so it (at least to me) makes sense to still have it on the unearned tab.

Comment: @Thomas: no, even Jon Skeet has not (still) every possible tag badge ! He is lacking ruby-on-rails-4 for the moment ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=tags&sort=votes&page=87)). Hope not being burnt to flame for saying that ;-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta he is ~`3840` badge away of having them all

Comment: Where do you get 3840 more badges from having all the bronze tag badges? Because by my calculation (and I just went through and calculated it because that doesn't look anywhere _near_ right and curiosity got the best of me) he's currently got 438 bronze tag badges. There are currently 13131 tags eligible for tag badges. (Went through and did the math for that myself.) Therefore, Jon Skeet needs 12693 more bronze tag badges to have all of them currently, and by the time he gets those more tags will likely be eligible.

Comment: @Kendra I did wrong math, I just counted the one where he already gave an answer

Comment: Hah, all of you smart people with tag badges...

Comment: Maybe it depends on the meaning of _unearned_. Maybe that's a page about people who have got those badges undeservedly ;) Seriously now, I did notice that the page does not have a user id in its url.

Answer (score 11):

Well I assume that even if you've gotten the c# tag badge, you still do not have a bronze badge in every possible tag(*). So yes, you can still earn tag badges in other tags, and it is normal that you still see it in your unearned page.

(*) I'm far from being able to earn all the badges, but even if you are, I would not dare until Jon does :-)

Comment: Sorry, but isn't it like a badge is _introduced after_ Jon had earned it? :P

Comment: @SouravGhosh Only the positive ones. Not those like [php], [wordpress], ... :P

Comment: @Siguza Jon has a silver badge in PHP. Current visible [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges&sort=name&page=10). (As he gets more badges, though, it'll move.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Hopefully just for answers pointing out flaws in PHP. :) Otherwise, it would imply that Jon actually _does_ have a fault related to programming, which might cause SO to crash.

Comment: @reirab No. Jon Skeet is just so good that he can actually write good code in a language as horrible as PHP.

Comment: @jpmc26 I was upset to discover that Jon hasn't earned enough badges in the last 11 hours to bump it off the page. I don't even know what to believe in anymore...

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the tag badges should disapear from the Unearned pages if you have reached bronze, silver or gold level in one tag.

It only would be consistent with the moderation badges for the review queue:

If I reviewed all 1000 Questions/Answers from **one queue**, the Custodian, Reviewer & Steward are not anymore at the Unearned page.